# SQL subtract hours, minutes, seconds from date

Tags: sql, oracle

DB: oracle

Is there a way or function to deduct below two sample data and get historic datetime in format (yyyymmdd hr24:mi:ss)?

```
1. Date: 20150324 13:05:22  (Date time)
2. Time: 125:36.25  (hr:mi.ss)

Sample expected result 

20150319 06:30:10
```

Comment: What is the data type of the two columns?

Comment: 20150324 13:05:22 (DATE)   125:36.25(VARCHAR2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample expected result is incorrect given your same data. It should be `2015-03-19 07:28:57`. Something like the below might work for you:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT timestamp'2015-03-24 13:05:22' AS mydate
         , '125:36.25' AS mytime FROM dual
)
SELECT mydate - NUMTODSINTERVAL( TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(mytime, 1, INSTR(mytime, ':') - 1))*3600
                               + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(mytime, INSTR(mytime, ':') + 1, 2))*60
                               + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(mytime, INSTR(mytime, '.') + 1, 2)), 'SECOND')
  FROM d1;
```

What I am doing in the above query is converting the "time" element to seconds and then to an `INTERVAL` value to subtract from the date/time value.

As an aside it would be better if the time column were an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` instead of a `VARCHAR2`. Then it could be used directly in date/timestamp arithmetic without needing to jump through any hoops.

Comment: thank you for wonderful explanation, expected result was just for data type sample, it was not exactly subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the second to fractional days and just subtracting from the first:

```
select (datecol - 
        (to_number(substr(hhmmss, -2)) / (60*24*24) +
         to_number(substr(hhmmss, -5, 2))/(60*24) +
         to_number(substr(hhmmss, instr(hhmmss, ':') - 1)/24
        )
       )
```

Comment: where to place time column within to_number function?

Comment: I've called the time column `hhmmss` because that is the format of the column.